# How can a potential energy function be used to sketch different levels of the wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

If the potential energy function is provided, say $V(x) = 5x^{2}$, how am I then able to use this function to visualize, graphically, the wavefunction where $V \neq \infty$?

Comment: Solve the Schrödinger equation and see. There is no shortcut.

Comment: Which one is supposed to be potential? $f$ or $V$?

Comment: @Feodoran, I clarified in the question; it should have been V(x) = 5x^2 when x > 0. I'm looking for more of a general process to go from having simply the function for potential to graphing the wavefunction.

Comment: I think this is a good question in the sense that if you haven't taken college-level physical chemistry, it isn't obvious that the eigenfunctions of $\hat{V}$ are the wavefunctions and the eigenvalues are the associated energies, and this is relatively complicated compared to just plotting the potential.

Comment: So, if I get this right, then the question is "How to solve the Schrödinger Equation?". This is a very broad question. There is a whole field trying to solve this problem in a general way.
For $V(x)=5x^2$ you have an [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator), which can be solved analytically.

Comment: @Feodoran, I figured out what the question was asking and it simplifies somewhat. It was really asking, given a function for potential, graph a few wavefunctions at different energy levels, demonstrating that you understand where the particle will behave as it should and where it begins tunneling, and comprehend how the difference in energy levels is changing.

Comment: Is that a [homework question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142)?

I still don't get the full question. Is it about sketching eigenfunctions or some wavefunction in general (which may be any arbitrary superposition of eigenfunctions) ?

Also this $V\neq\infty$ is confusting, since we already have $V(x)=5x^2$.

About tunneling: That requires some barrier in the potential, which we don't have in the harmonic oscillator.